# Will Muslims see Prophet Esa?

Tags: prophet-isa, yajooj-and-majooj, dajjal

I have heard that when time gets closer to judgement day, jooj majooj will come out and eat everything on Earth other than sand. Also Dajjal will be here too and Prophet Esa will kill Dajjal with his sword. Before all this happens there will be a huge tornado like wind which will take all Muslims with it and only the kufr will be left.

Does this mean that Muslims will not get to see Prophet Esa?

Also if jooj majooj eat everything (even eachother) then shouldn't they eat Dajjal?

Comment: Assalaamualaikum , will a video link do it for you? Dajjal will be the first to come followed by Esa (alayhisalam) . Hajooj majooj will come quite later.

Comment: I think your getting the events that will happen backward, first the Dajjal, then Mahdi and Isa, then Ya'jooj and Ma'jooj, then a while after that a light wind comes and takes the souls of the believers.

Comment: Sorry I should have said I wanted Sunni view

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you got the timeline wrong:

> **Anas (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: “The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: ‘The Dajjal will
>   emerge from among the Jews of Isfahaan, and with him will be seventy
>   thousand Jews, wearing crowns.’” (Narrated by Ahmad, no. 12865).**

With the help of hadiths we get to know the duration for which Dajjal would stay on Earth would be 40 days out of which 1st day would be equivalent to a year, 2nd to a month and the 3rd to a week whilst the remaining 37 days would be the same as ordinary days.

> **Prophet Muhammad صلى الله عليه وسلم  said : "He (Dajjal) will rule on Earth for 40 days, but they will not be like other days. They are:
>   'Forty days, one of these days will be like a year, another day like a
>   month, yet another like a week, and the rest (the remaining 37 days)
>   will have the same length as normal days '. The companions who were
>   always concerned about the matters of faith and worship, asked Prophet
>   Muhammad صلى الله عليه وسلم  : 'O Messenger of Allah, for the day
>   which is like a year, will one day's prayers be sufficient?' He said:
>   'No, you must estimate the time and observe the (regular daily)
>   prayers'.” (Sahih Muslim)**

The coming of Esa (alayhi salaam):

> **Prophet Mohammed صلى الله عليه وسلم said: "In the meantime, while the Dajjal will be busy doing this and this, Allah will send down the
>   Messiah son of Mary (Jesus عليه السلام). He (Jesus عليه السلام ) will
>   descend in the eastern part of Damascus, near the white minaret
>   (tower), dressed in the two yellowish garments, with his hands resting
>   on the arms of two angels. When he will bend down his head, water
>   drops will appear trickling down, and when he will raise it, it will
>   appear as though pearl--like drops are rolling down. Any disbeliever
>   whom the air of his breath reaches, and it will reach up to the last
>   limit of his sight, will fall dead. Then, the son of Mary will go in
>   pursuit of the Dajjal, and will overtake him at the gate of Lud and
>   will kill him." (Sahih Muslim, Tirmizi, and Ibn Majah).**

If you see, the following hadith describes the interaction between Imam Mahdi and Esa (alayhi salaam) which means Muslims recognize Esa.

> **Jesus son of Mary would then descend and their (Muslims') commander would invite him to come and lead them in prayer, but he would say:
>   No, some amongst you are commanders over some (amongst you). This is
>   the honour from Allah for this Ummah. (Sahih Muslim, Book 001, Number
>   0293)**

You can see, Dajjal comes first, followed by Eesa whereas during the time of Hajooj Majooj,

> **...Then a people whom Allah had protected would come to Jesus, son of Mary, and he would wipe their faces and would inform them of their
>   ranks in Paradise and it would be under such conditions that Allah
>   would reveal to Jesus these words: I have brought forth from amongst
>   My servants such people against whom none would be able to fight; you
>   take these people safely to Tur, and then Allah would send Gog and
>   Magog and they would swarm down from every slope. The first of them
>   would pass the lake of Tibering and drink out of it. And when the last
>   of them would pass, he would say: There was once water there. Jesus
>   and his companions would then be besieged here (at Tur, and they would
>   be so much hard pressed) that the head of the ox would be dearer to
>   them than one hundred dinirs and Allah's Apostle, Jesus, and his
>   companions would supplicate Allah, Who would send to them insects
>   (which would attack their necks) and in the morning they would perish
>   like one single person**
>   **Sahih Muslim Book 041, Hadith Number 7015.**

Well, this is a really huge topic but to answer your question, you can see that Esa (alayhi salam) is already present when Hagog and Magog come on earth. We can also see that Esa slays Dajjal soon after he comes. As for Dajjal, there are normal signs which are happening nowadays which indicates he will be the first to come.

Here's the order: Dajjal--Eesa(Alayhi salaam)--Hagog/Magog. Dajjal wont be there at the time of Hagog Magog. Hope this answers the question. As of the strong wind, it will come after all of this.

And Allah knows best!! Baarakallahu Feekum..

Comment: according to shia scholars the hadith about Isfahaan is not authentic.

Answer (score 3):

**Will Muslims see Prophet Esa?**
- Yes.

[Narrated Abu Hurayrah](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/39/34):

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said:
>   When **you see** Jesus, *recognise* him: a man of medium height, etc etc . He will fight the people **for the cause of Islam**. He will break the cross, kill swine, and abolish jizyah. Allah will perish all religions **except Islam**. He will *destroy the Antichrist* and will *live on the earth for forty years* and then he will die. The **Muslims will pray over him**.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is two part. one about seeing Jesus a.s. and one about yajooj majooj.

About jooj majooj some hadith said it from signs of judgement day and some said it from signs of rise of Imam Mahdi a.s.. that are confused in some Islamic books.

But those ahadeeth say only they will return and no hadith could be could about found about eating everything.

About seeing Jesus a.s. yes, prophet Jesus a.s. will return and will pray behind Imam Mahdi a.s. when his occultation finishes and he starts his rise and revolution.

Jesus a.s. will be one of commanders of Imam Mahdi a.s. and Jesus a.s. will lead the peace between Muslims and Christians and so Muslims and Christians will be united against Jews and the war will happen between Muslims and Jews and finally The Bayt al Muqaddas (Jerusalem) will be freed and will be under control of Muslims.

You can read more about Jesus' second coming (according to Shi'ite narrations) here: http://www.al-islam.org/jesus-though-shiite-narrations-mahdi-muntazir-qaim/his-second-coming

Answer (score 2):

According to authentic narrations in Saheeh Muslim, Prophet 'Eesa (Peace be upon him) will descend at the end of times as a just judge. He will break the cross, kill the pigs, and abolish the *jizyah*(tax paid by non-Muslims in an Islamic state). At that time, money will become so widespread that there will be none left to accept it.

In another similar authentic *Muttafqun 'alaih* (narration which is agreed upon by both Imam Bukhari and Imam Muslim) narration, Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “By the One in Whose hand is my soul, soon the son of Maryam will descend among you [according to another report: the Hour will not begin until the son of Maryam descends among you] as a just judge. He will break the cross, kill the pigs and abolish the jizyah, and money will become abundant until no one will accept it.” [Bukhari, Muslim]

Yes, Muslims will definitely see him. He will appear to kill Dajjal the false Messiah, and fight Gog and Magog and destroy them. He will meet Imam Mahdi and pray behind him. Then he will rule the world according to Islamic Shari'ah. He will stay on earth as long as Allah wills. After that, he will die a natural death, and the Muslims will offer the funeral prayer for him. It is said that he will be buried beside Prophet Muhammad (Peace and Blessings be upon him) but it's not a confirmed report.

Comment: Salaam and thank you for your nice answer! Would you also consider citing your sources completely? Maybe by adding direct links?

Comment: Ok I'll try In Shaa Allah. Assalamu 'Alaikum.